# Using google maps iOS framework, how to convert lat/lng to pixels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, coordinates, pixel

In my iOS project (obj-c) I use `GoogleMaps` framework with markers and I try to find a way to convert markers coordinates lat/lng to pixels.
I found functions from other system, like java with API V3, but it seems it's not possible with iOS ? Functions does not exist ?
Any ideas ?

To complete my question on "why I need it ?" :

I also use the second framework `google-maps-ios-utils` for clustering. But it's not possible currently to show an `infoWindow`with a tap on the makers.
It's just possible if I use markers from `GoogleMap`framework.

So I try to find a solution to build myself an infoWindow, but to do this I need the coordinates in pixels from the current marker !

Comment: Why you want to get the pixels what you want to achieve with it ?

Comment: If you want to get CGPoint of marker you can get it by 

CGPoint point = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];

NSLog(@"Point for coordinate is %f", coordinate)

Comment: that would depend  on the zoom level + CLLocationCoordinate2D of the annotation + position of the mapview.

Comment: Thanks Manish, that's what I'm looking for !